Trouble Extracting and Utilizing Tokens Across Thread Groups Using JSR223 Preprocessor
I am trying to use JSR223 preprocessor to extract token from login and using it in other thread group of my test plan, but i am not getting it , i tried to add debugger , but token is not present in, refer image for the plan


If you want to extract something from the response using a JSR223 test element you need to use the JSR223 PostProcessor, not the JSR223 PreProcessor.

PreProcessors are executed before any Sampler in their scope
PostProcessors are executed after any Sampler in their scope and you can get response data, headers, etc. using prev shorthand for the SampleResult class instance

See Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups article for more information.
